# Problems with IE 11 when using a Bootstrap carousel together with youtube iframe api

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, youtube

I am working on a small wordpress template which should allow the admin to create a bootstrap carousal with youtube videos. The carousal should stop when a video is played and the video playing should stop if the user click to the next slide.

It works well in most browsers I have tested in (chrome,firefox and safari), but I have two problems in IE 11.

1. When I try to use functions such as player.pauseVideo() I get the error ‘object doesn't support property or method 'pauseVideo’.
2. The second problem is when the carousal display an iframe for the second time. In this case a black screen with play button is displayed rather than the image displayed before a video is played. When you click the play button the video load as it should.

I am pretty new in this field so I hope someone can help. I have posted the code below.

UPDATE:
I uninstalled the IE 11 update so i am back to IE 10 and now the first problem i gone... So i will try and update againg.

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="video-container darkBlueBorder item <?php if( $the_query->current_post == 0 ):?>active<?php endif; ?>" >
            <div class="musicVideo" id="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtube_url", true) ?>"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" style="bottom: 40px;" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" style="bottom: 40px;" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//Start Carousel
jQuery('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
});


//Start Youtube API
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var youtubeReady = false;

//Variable for the dynamically created youtube players
var players= new Array();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
youtubeReady = true;
//The id of the iframe is the same as the videoId   
jQuery(".musicVideo").each(function(i, obj) {
    players[obj.id] = new YT.Player(obj.id, {         
        videoId: obj.id,
        playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0 ,
            wmode: "opaque"
         },   
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
 });
}

jQuery('.carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if(youtubeReady){
        var iframeID = jQuery(this).find('.active').find('iframe').attr("id");
        window.alert(iframeID);
        players[iframeID].pauseVideo();
        jQuery('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
    }  
});

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch(event.data){
        case 0:
            jQuery('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
            break;
        case 1:
            jQuery('.carousel').carousel('pause');
            break;
        default:
            console.log("otherwise");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
I solved the problem with the black preview images by forcing the youtube player to be an html5 player. This also solved some serious framerate issues i had in IE. So I simply added "html5: 1" to the playerVars.